# my ArrayList is overwriting previous data

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying simple `ArrayList` example to solve some problem with my other code but this simple code is giving wrong output.

I have create an Arraylist of Hashmap, put 3 key/value pairs in that Hashmap and then put that Hashmap in the ArrayList, like this,

```
public class SortData {

    public static void main (String [] args){

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();


        myHashMap.put("title",  "first Title");
        myHashMap.put("date",   "This is date");
        myHashMap.put("number", "5");

        myArrayList.add(0, myHashMap);
```

but when I try to add more data in the array list,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SortData {

    public static void main (String [] args){

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();


        myHashMap.put("title",  "first Title");
        myHashMap.put("date",   "This is date");
        myHashMap.put("number", "5");

        myArrayList.add(0, myHashMap);


        myHashMap.put("title",  "Second Title");
        myHashMap.put("date",   "This is 2nd date");
        myHashMap.put("number", "2");

        myArrayList.add(1, myHashMap);

        myHashMap.put("title",  "Third Title");
        myHashMap.put("date",   "This is 3rd date");
        myHashMap.put("number", "7");

        myArrayList.add(2, myHashMap);


        System.out.println(myArrayList.get(0)+"");
        System.out.println(myArrayList.get(1)+"");
        System.out.println(myArrayList.get(2)+"");


    }


}
```

The output is,

```
{title=Third Title, number=7, date=This is 3rd date}
{title=Third Title, number=7, date=This is 3rd date}
{title=Third Title, number=7, date=This is 3rd date}
```

Why the previous values in `ArrayList` are overwritten ? 
I have tried both,

`myArrayList.add(Hashmap())`, and `myArrayList.add(int index, Hashmap())`
but the output is the same

Comment: You misunderstand how object references and method invocation works.

Comment: How many HashMap's do you think you've created? (hint: look for the 'new' keyword).

Comment: I have created one `hashmap` and then overwrite values in it

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, could you please link me to any article where i can learn about those concepts ?

Comment: [Lesson: Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Comment: If you've only created one HashMap, why do you expect to be able to print out three different ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ArrayList` adds a reference to the `HashMap` that you've added, not a copy.  You're adding the same `HashMap` to the `ArrayList` 3 times.  After each add, you change the contents with more `put` calls, which overwrite the pre-existing values, because of the same key.

```
myArrayList[ o , o , o ]
             |   |   |
             +---+   |
             |       |
             +-------+
             |
             v
             myHashMap
```

To add different contents, add different `HashMap`s each time, by running

```
myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

after the first 2 `add`s.

```
myArrayList[ o , o , o ]
             |   |   +-> HashMap
             |   |   
             |   +-----> HashMap
             |
             +---------> HashMap
```

Comment: thank you , and sorry for a dumb question but you said " which overwrite the pre-existing values, because of the same key." if it over writes pre-existing values why it hasn't updated ?

Comment: The HashMap did "update".  E.g. after the second `add`, you have `{"title" -> "Second Title", "date" -> "This is 2nd date", "number", "2"}`.  After the last `add`, the 3 `put` calls have changed it to `{"title" -> "Third Title", "date" -> "This is 3rd date", "number", "7"}`.

Comment: Really simple mistake to do, thanks this helped me :)